# get _id of mongodb document that we insert if it doesn't exist and update if it already exists

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a collection subscribers that has unique index on {LISTID:1, EMAIL:1}.
I want to insert a document if it doesn't exist and update it if already exists, but in any case I want to get _id of the document not matter if it's inserted or updates.

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->test; 
$collection = $db->subscribers;
$criteria = array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com');
$data = array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com', 'FNAME' => 'Oleg');
$result = $collection->update($criteria, $data, array('fsync' => true, 'upsert' => true));    
var_dump($data);
var_dump($result);
```

If the document is inserted, I get in result:

```
array
  'LISTID' => int 86
  'EMAIL' => string 'opp20071980@gmail.com' (length=21)
  'FNAME' => string 'Oleg' (length=4)

array
          'updatedExisting' => boolean false
          'upserted' => 
            object(MongoId)[6]
              public '$id' => string '506446e4e0dae94a0bd25d06' (length=24)
          'n' => int 1
          'connectionId' => int 10
          'fsyncFiles' => int 7
          'err' => null
          'ok' => float 1
```

But if it's updated I get result without _id:

```
array
  'LISTID' => int 86
  'EMAIL' => string 'opp20071980@gmail.com' (length=21)
  'FNAME' => string 'Oleg' (length=4)
array
  'updatedExisting' => boolean true
  'n' => int 1
  'connectionId' => int 10
  'fsyncFiles' => int 7
  'err' => null
  'ok' => float 1
```

Could you please tell me how to get _id even if record is updated, but not inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `MongoCollection.update()` will not return an `_id` (just like `MongoCollection.insert()`

If there **is no** match in the database and you have `upsert=>true`, you'll get an `id` inside the `upserted` object. Not if there **is** a match.

If you want to update or insert a single document, you can use the **`findAndModify`** command with `upsert` (helper added in v.1.3.0-beta)

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $m->mydatabase;
$query = array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com');
$update = array('$set' => array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com', 'FNAME' => 'Oleg') );

$result = $db->command(
  array(
    "findandmodify" => "test", / /name of collection
    "query" => $query,
    "update" => $update,
    'upsert' => 1
  )
);
```

The result in both situations will be different, see here:

Record found, updated:

```
Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 506470963e20d69457000000
                )

            [LISTID] => 86
            [EMAIL] => opp20071980@gmail.com
        )

    [lastErrorObject] => Array
        (
            [updatedExisting] => 1
            [n] => 1
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

No record found, inserted:

```
Array
(
    [value] => 
    [lastErrorObject] => Array
        (
            [updatedExisting] => 
            [n] => 1
            [upserted] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 5064708213995e82a829753e
                )

        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

You'll have to do get the `_id` in two different places depending if the findAndModify inserted or updated the document.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$data` variable with `$set` and try again.

```
$data =  array('$set' => array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com', 'FNAME' => 'Oleg'));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The result is the same: array
  'updatedExisting' => boolean true
  'n' => int 1
  'connectionId' => int 10
  'fsyncFiles' => int 7
  'err' => null
  'ok' => float 1

Comment: What is will be result of `var_dump($collection->findOne(array('LISTID' => 86, 'EMAIL' => 'opp20071980@gmail.com')));`

Comment: Something like this: array
  'EMAIL' => string 'opp20071980@gmail.com' (length=21)
  'FNAME' => string 'Oleg' (length=4)
  'LISTID' => int 86
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[6]
      public '$id' => string '50645fe9e0dae94a0bd25d07' (length=24)

Comment: It returns document is such document already exists. But then the document exists, and this operation updates it, the id is not returned.

Comment: Try to print_r `$criteria` and `$data` after update and check it have `[_id]` in it. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: $data doesn't contain _id after this operation.

Comment: Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I  don't know exactly more about this.  I think only insert will get mongo  id , not in case of update .